# Checkbox onclick uncheck other checkboxes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have 6 checkboxes, one for each business day and one that says 'all'.

What i want to be able to do is uncheck all the other boxes if someone clicks the 'all' checkbox if that makes sense.

For example, if someone has clicked monday and wednesday ... then they come in and click the 'all' checkbox, then the monday and wednesday checkbox should uncheck.

Cheers,

Comment: Normally a user would check `all` when he wants to check all the checkboxes. Is this you want?

Comment: I would do it that way .... but the people im doing it for want it the other way around, when the user clicks all, all the rest of the checkboxes uncheck except the all one.

Comment: And which part are you having trouble with?  Or should we just Give You Teh Codez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not you want, but seems to be more sensible.

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkAll" />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkMonday" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTuesday" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkWednesday" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkThursday" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkFriday" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSaturday" class="child" />
<input type="checkbox" id="chkSunday" class="child" />
```

jQUery

```
$(function(){
    $("#chkAll").change(function(){
        if (this.checked) {
            $("input:checkbox.child").attr("checked", "checked");
        }
        else {
            $("input:checkbox.child").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

See a [**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWWsF/)

See an [**updated version**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWWsF/1/) which handles change in the child checkboxes also.

Comment: that's not exactly what the op wanted but it should give him the way.

Comment: Sweet, thats perfect ... just need to mod it a bit, but thanks heaps

Answer (score 1):

jquery and some code like this should do it.

```
$('#all-id').change(function(){
   if($('#all-id').is(':checked')){
     if($('#monday-id').is(':checked')){
        $('#monday-id').attr('checked', false);
     } else {
       $('#monday-id').attr('checked', true);
     }
     // etc
   }
});
```

After you might want to put all the ids in an array and setup a loop or play with the structure of your document to be able to easily loop on all of those checkboxes